# Using Mac to create bootable usb stick for Windows

Tags: usb

What directions should i be following to use my friends mac to create a bootable usb stick for an old hp pavilion dv4?

The hp pavilion doesn't seem to have any operating system, it tries to boot windows but it's 'missing' something and tells me I need to install Windows, but I'd rather install ubuntu. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UNetbootin** . Download from [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Download Ubuntu iso from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Documentation on how to install Ubuntu from USB stick [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)